# Hello im getting this error: TypeError: User is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication

I'm getting this error: `TypeError: User is not a function`

I guess i made a misstake in my `user.js`,

There is the code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
/ User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
        password: {
        type: String
    },
        email: {
        type: String
    },
        name: {
        type: String
    }
});
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    var query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

Can help me solve this problem

Comment: I assume this is javascript; please confirm.

Comment: Programing language: JavaScript, DB: mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a transcription error, but the line `/ User Schema` is syntactically incorrect; if you mean it to be a comment, you need `//` at the beginning.